# Effective seasonal decomposition using STL on entire Pandas DataFrame / vectorized?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am doing seasonal decomposition of around 1000 columns

There are two classic libraries that I know off `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL` and `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal_decompose`

The problem with `seasonal_decompose` is that it will return `NaN` for half a period in beginning and end (you can extrapolate the trend, but it is usually not very effective) it is also not as robust against outliers as `STL`.

However, `seasonal_decompose` can take an entire DataFrame in one call, and decompose each column independently.

```
 %%time
 statsmodels.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df.values,model='additive',period=288,extrapolate_trend=0)

 CPU times: user 35.4 ms, sys: 3.21 ms, total: 38.6 ms
 Wall time: 35.8 ms
```

While STL library only takes one array at a time as input, so I would need to iterate over each column which would take a lot of time.

```
%%time
for col in df.columns:
    sd = statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL(df[col],period=288)
    sd.fit()

 CPU times: user 1min 52s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1min 52s
 Wall time: 1min 52s
```

So I was wondering if there exists some library or way to apply STL in some vectorized approach so that I can apply it on an entire DataFrame at once so that it's faster than iterating over each column?

Comment: I don't think a vectorized implementation exists.  You could, however, use multiprocessing (via joblib or some other abstraction) to parallelize the computation. It should then take around 112s / ncpu.

Answer (score 0):

I investigate only `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL`, same could be applied to `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal_decompose`.

I use example data from `STL` documentation that I duplicate 100 time.

```
from statsmodels.datasets import co2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL
from pandarallel import pandarallel

data = co2.load(True).data
data = data.resample('M').mean().ffill()
n_duplic = 100
for i in range(n_duplic):
    data['co2_%d' % i] = data['co2']
```

I defined the function where `s` is a pandas serie or a 1D array :

```
def func(s):
    return STL(s).fit()
```

with apply (range time 850-900ms):

```
%%time
data.apply(func, axis=0)

CPU times: user 880 ms, sys: 4.11 ms, total: 884 ms
Wall time: 884 ms
```

with pandarallel (range time 240-250ms, 8 processes, need to be initialized):

```
pandarallel.initialize()

%%time
res = data.parallel_apply(func, axis=0)

CPU times: user 37.5 ms, sys: 56.4 ms, total: 94 ms
Wall time: 254 ms
```

speed improvement close to a factor of 4